# программно вызвать событие EditingControlShowing в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

есть функция которая грузит данные в таблицу

```
private void LoadGridMain()
```

один из столбцов содержит DataGridViewComboBox.

Включено событие EditingControlShowing

```
ComboBox cb;
private Point lastcell;
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            lastcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
            cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            cb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cb_DrawItem);
            cb.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(cb_DropDownClosed);
            cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Set_value_ComboSelectionChanged);
        }
    }
```

Событие cb.DrawItem строит сложное представление выпадающего списка.

Событие cb.SelectedIndexChanged обрабатывает выбор. В конце события надо вызвать перегрузку всех данных в таблице повторным вызовом LoadGridMain(). И вот тут происходит следующая проблема - Если выбрать мышкой любую другую ячейку, то проблемы нет. Если тапнуть на ту же ячейку из предыдущего выбора, то программа выпадает в исключение, т.к. не вызывается EditingControlShowing и соответственно список пустой(не вызывается cb.DrawItem). Код сразу попадает в cb.SelectedIndexChanged).
Не могу добиться повторного запуска EditingControlShowing.
Пробовал играться с

```
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
dataGridView1.Rows[lastcell.Y].Cells[lastcell.X].Selected = false;
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Всё это работает, если указываю ячейку отличную от предыдущей. если указываю туже самую, то нету запуска события EditingControlShowing, хоть тресни.

**UPG**
написал такой костыль, но сути так и не понял

```
private void Set_value_ComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// код функции .....
  LoadGridMain();
  dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(this, new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs(cb, dataGridView1.Rows[lastcell.Y].Cells[lastcell.X].Style));
}
```

получается dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing вызывается первый раз при выборе ячейки(как и должно быть), второй раз при выборе значения из списка. При клике на туже ячейку происходит опять вызов dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing. Что происходит при вызове "второй" раз?

**UPD2**
Подсказка в комментариях помогла. Достаточно отписаться перед перезагрузкой данных

```
private void Set_value_ComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // код функции .....
 cb.DrawItem -= new DrawItemEventHandler(cb_DrawItem);
 cb.DropDownClosed -= new EventHandler(cb_DropDownClosed);
 cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(Set_value_ComboSelectionChanged);
LoadGridMain();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[lastcell.Y].Cells[lastcell.X];
}
```

Comment: Нужно отписываться от событий. Смотрите примечание в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks). И по ссылке смотрите пример кода DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.

Comment: если вы про события cb, то я их отключаю при изменении lastcels. Само событие dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing  зачем отключать? Я наоборот не могу заставить его сработать при выборе той же ячейки при перезагрузки таблицы. А в нём я так предполагаю главным будет cb = e.Control as ComboBox;

Comment: Вы пробовали отписываться от событий, как указано в документации [DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples)? `cb.DrawItem -= new DrawItemEventHandler(cb_DrawItem);` и т. д.

Comment: да, если этого не сделать, то они накладываются друг на друга при каждом вызове EditingControlShowing и срабатывают многократно.

Comment: Напишите ответ как положено, а не в самом вопросе. И потом примите ответ. И вам плюс в репутацию, и кому-нибудь ещё помочь может.

Comment: Что- бы написать ответ нужно чётко понимать суть проблемы, а у меня знаний ноль. Например, почему  событие cb.DrawItem отрабатывает первее EditingControlShowing. У меня мозг рушится от такого поведения.

Comment: Я немного поэкспериментировал. Мне не удалось повторить поведение. Нужно знать больше деталей. Как попадают данные в грид: напрямую или с помощью привязки данных? Используется ли промежуточный класс BindingSource? Хотя, в любом случае, это не должно влиять на последовательность вызова событий. Так-то понятно, что после загрузки новых данных меняется текущая колонка (на первую с индексом 0). Поэтому вы устанавливаете CurrentCell - и вот тут-то что-то случается... Но если проблема решена с помощью UPD2, то и хорошо.